# Using a second dedicated server as backup?

Tags: backup

I've been looking at various different options for backuping my main web server.  I need 500GB+ of backup.  I feel the easiest/most robust option is just to have a second server (owned by a different company, in a different datacentre...) that I rsync everything to every day?

This also actually seems to be the cheapest option (for 1TB of space) as well.  Ordered a kimsufi server for €9.99/month last night.  It's weak on memory & cpu compared to my main box, but obviously I don't need those things.

This also gives me the option of falling over to that server entirely if I have a catastrophic failure on my current box.

I feel most people go for a "cloud" option for their backup.  Am I missing a trick?

I suppose one thing I need to be careful of is if some bad code (malicious or just buggy) removes/screws my sites on box 1, I need to make sure those changes aren't replicated to box 2 before I get to fix it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you suggest is actually what a lot of people do in fact, for exactly the reasons it appeals to you - especially if the second site is ran on wildly different architecture - it's a very sensible option indeed. As for the buggy/malicious angle consider rsyncing asynchronously, every hour/four-hours/daily, that way you have a window of time to stop syncing the 'bad', also consider periodic filesystem snapshotting to prevent similar.

Comment: I would consider rsnapshot: http://www.rsnapshot.org/

Comment: I guess I didn't want to assume he was on an *nix OS

Comment: Codemonkey's post history gave a strong hint he's talking about *nix OS, likely CentOS. :)

Comment: Good spot, well said

Comment: Plus didn't the mention of rsync in the topic point to that? ;) Ah no, wiki tells me there's a Windows port of it.  News to me!

Thanks for validating my choice @Chopper :)